# Filter empty date field in SF analytics api

Tags: api, datetime, filters, analytics, gack

Using the analytics rest api we need to add a filter to a date field to get only the records where this field is empty.
In json:

```
{
    "column": "Account.Date_Field__c",
    "operator": "equals",
    "value": ""
},
```

This filter is also shown if you fetch the report meta data from SF, so the syntax should be correct.

Till the rollout of Summer 14 release it was working a sexpected, after the release change we get the error message

> Filter the date in the correct format. Accepted formats are yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z' and yyyy-MM-dd.

I checked to use null, but this leads to an error "574902135-2760 (-2136086741)"

Any ideas how to filter on empty date field?

Comment: Did you ever solve your problem with this, perhaps by trying `isEmpty` or something similar?

Comment: So you could work around the issue with a formula field, `isDateFieldBlank__c`,  but i think you should go ahead and contact support with a bug report. Looking at the metadata returned by the analytics api with a filter of equals blank it matches the JSON you're supplying.

Answer (score 0):

when you pull the date field `Account.Date_Field__c` it creates `Date_field__c_day_epoch` and `Date_field__c_sec_epoch` fields. if these fields are having value as null or 0 then `Account.Date_Field__c` is either blank or Null or 1970-01-01. may be  you can filter based on `Date_field__c_sec_epoch` to get the nulls or blanks values.